# how to install scrapy under python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, installation

i have installed twisted,lxml,scrapy successively using cmd.When i import scrapy in cmd window,it doesn't raise exception.[image]

but when i import scrapy in spyder,it raise exception like following:
[image]

i wonder if there are some solutions?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have installed scrappy using pip under windows correct?

The issue at hand has everything to do with python and spyder being able to see the install. I had similar issues with opencv when first installing.

The get around this, I compiled both opencv and python together and installed them.

I vote you try and perform the install using the python console in spyder.

```
 pip install scrampy
```

Comment: are you saying that i should input pip install scrapy in spyder directly? if that is true,i think this approach won't work

Comment: Then the other option is to compile both python and scrampy together.

Comment: how to complie python and scrapy together

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the python 3 upon python 2?
If true, the scrapy may be integrated to python 2.
confirm the version with this instruction in the command line.

```
python --version
```

If it says Python 2.7.x, you tested on the python 2 when trying with cmd.
Let me know you have both of version on your computer.

Comment: it say python 3.4.2

Comment: Check the c drive if C:\Python27 directory exists.